# Gatsby Link absolute path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

By using `Link` component in Gatsby.js I will not be able to directed by clickin on a link to back to previous urls ,
e.g: I have this url `site.com/article/id` let's say I am in the `id` page , so in this case when I use `Link` I will not be able to go to `site.com/article/id2` but instead I will be only be able to go `site.com/article/id/article/id2` . How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a slash (`/`) the beginning of the `to` prop:

```
<Link to={`/${someSlugVar}`} />Click me</Link>
```

Otherwise, it concatenates the new slug to the current one because of the relativity of the paths. In the end, it behaves like a normal anchor so the approach is exactly the same (your issue will also happen using a normal `<a>`).